# not able to open shared folder in my PC

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, sharepoint-2010

I shared my folders in my PC. When I am trying to check it with my computer in network - \Kapil

My PC name: \Kapil

its giving me an error:
"Please check the spelling of the name or there might be a problem with network"
"remote device won't accept connection"

in window 7.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a vague question so I would start with some general network troubleshooting:

1. Are you trying to access the remote computer via SMB/CIFS or HTTP?
2. Have you got a Webserver installed and running on the server computer?
3. Are you able to do what you are trying from the console on the server computer?
4. Have you configured firewalls on client & server computers and all network devices in between?

Comment: I don't know, The problem got resolved after restarting..